# Is there any operator to move files across different hosts via SFTP using Airflow?

Tags: rsync, airflow

A noob to Airflow ecosystem. One of my first goals using Airflow is implementing workflows to move files across machines. In particular, I'm looking for ways to consolidate data from different Mac/Linux machines into a NAS (using SFTP).

I've been exploring the different Airflow operators and most of the transfer ones copy data from local machine to cloud services. I haven't seen anyone to copy files from host to host, neither one to move (or copy, then check, then delete). I assume I could use BashOperator to move or use rsync with files. Is there any best practice in this regard on how to move files across different hosts via SFTP using Airflow? Any pattern to copy/check/delete safely?

Answer (score 0):

There is not.

However, you can create your own operators as plugins:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/plugins.html

You may wanna take advantage of SftpHook existing in Airflow to code your operator:
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will check the documentation and try different alternatives to see which one works more reliably. The thing that surprises me more, is that no one else needs to delete their files after sending them somewhere else. Is that some kind of pattern in ETL processing like, never delete source files from the pipeline itself. Just wondering!